# Не получается задать метки узлов графа networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

При отрисовке графа не получается задать определенные метки для каждого узла. Согласно документации, для отрисовки меток используется метод [draw_networkx_labels](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_labels.html), но почему то не получается(хотя раньше как то делал).

Вот используемый код:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# получим метки узлов
# 1 -> 111
labels = dict((i, str(i)*3) for i in range(5))

# рисуем граф
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=False)
# рисуем метки
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos, labels=labels)
plt.savefig('labels.png')
```

Должно получится вот такое, но не получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выяснилось данная проблема появляется в pycharm, в jupyter notebook же отрабатывает все как надо.

Comment: а что вас не устраивет в картинке графа?

Comment: @MaxU то что на картинке, это то что я хотел бы получить.

Comment: запустив ваш код я получаю то, что на картинке, только узлы немного повернуты по часовой стрелке...

Comment: Какие у вас версии `NetworkX` и `matplotlib`?

Comment: @MaxU а вот это интересно, так как я уже и говорил, раньше у меня это получалось, networkx - 2.2, matplotlib - 3.0.2, python - 3.7.1, а у Вас какие версии?

Comment: Версии модулей такие же как у вас, вот только Python - 3.6.8

Comment: Вы можете привести в вопросе "неправильную" картинку - ту что у вас получается?

Comment: @MaxU в том что и проблема, что в итоге просто пустая картинка, но функция nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, with_labels=False) отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: вы пробовали открыть новый терминал Jupyter/iPython и запустить в нем только код из вашего вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU именно в jupyter не пробовал, делаю это в IDE (pycharm), сейчас попробую в notebook

Comment: @MaxU Да, вы правы в Jupyter все как надо отработало....интересно в чем тогда проблема.

Comment: тут я врядли вам смогу помочь - я pycharm практически не использовал...

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо большое, теперь я хоты бы понимаю в какую сторону рыть.

Comment: Переустановка IDE +интерпретатора решила проблему - еще раз спасибо @MaxU